# JS UTC timestamp behaviour

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how this time conversion works. I have timestamp 1462060800000 which when I turn in to date correctly becomes:
Sun May 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

but then when I want to get the month with const startMonth = start.getUTCMonth() I get 4 instead of 5. Why is this happening and what do I need to do to get the correct month?

```js
const timestamp = 1462060800000
const start = new Date(timestamp)
console.log(start) // Sun May 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

const startYear = start.getUTCFullYear()
const startMonth = start.getUTCMonth()
console.log(startMonth) // 4
```

Comment: if your question is solved, please mark one answer as accepted answer.

Comment: Read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getUTCMonth()` returns zero-based months. 4 is correct. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get it it's actually a month index that starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

> The getUTCMonth() returns the month of the specified date according to universal time, **as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)**.

From the docs see [Date.prototype.getUTCMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth)

Answer (score 0):

The `getUTCMonth()` method, like `getMonth()`, has a zero (0) count. This means that the period will be like this - `0 and 11`. To get the desired month, you need to add `+1`:

```
const startMonth = start.getUTCMonth() + 1;
```

[Loot it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth).

```js
const timestamp = 1462060800000;
const start = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(start); // Sun May 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

const startYear = start.getUTCFullYear();
const startMonth = start.getUTCMonth() + 1;
console.log(startMonth);
```